# Gtk+ Delete padding/margin of first column on Gtk::Treeview

Tags: c++, treeview, gtk3, gtkmm

I need that the first column of Gtk :: TreeView has "ALIGN_LEFT" like timestamp column and others.

[image]

I tried this:

```
Gtk::TreeViewColumn* numberColumn = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::TreeViewColumn("#", treeModel->getModelColumn(FIRST_COLUMN)));
Gtk::CellRendererText* const renderNumber = static_cast<Gtk::CellRendererText*>(number->get_first_cell());

renderNumber->set_alignment(0.0, 0.0);
renderNumber->set_padding(0, 0);
```

but I get the same behavior. I'm using Gtk3 version 3.10.8-0ubuntu1 on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for answer my own question, I was desperate and documentation is not very friendly.

That space is reserved for arrow that expand a row with children.

Solution:

```
m_treeView.set_show_expanders(false);
```

Comment: Are you using a ListStore or TreeStore?

Comment: I created a "CustomTreeModel" that implement  GtkTreeModel like ListStore or TreeStore.

Comment: Does it happen if you use a ListStore, for instance in a simple test case.

Comment: @murrayc Let me test it, I think that whether it happen, the default behavior should be false.

Comment: @murrayc It doesn't happen whether I use ListStore. Which property should set on my custom model?

Comment: Well done for finding that out. Then it's as I suspected. I guess you need to specify GTK_TREE_MODEL_LIST_ONLY: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeModel.html#GtkTreeModelFlags . And I guess you need to do this by returning it from a vfunc, as I do in Glom: https://git.gnome.org/browse/glom/tree/glom/mode_data/datawidget/treemodel_db.cc#n405